# Cannot set duration for carouFredSel Slider

Tags: jquery, caroufredsel

I am using `carouFredSel` to make Slider, but duration cannot be set. It may run default.

I set like :

```
$("#foo6").carouFredSel({
    auto: true,
    responsive: true,
    duration: 2000,
    prev: "#prev6",
    next: "#next6",
    scroll: 1,
    pagination: "#pager6",
    mousewheel: true,
    items: {
        visible: 1,
        width: 200
    }
});
```

Say me solution for my issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
$('#carousel').carouFredSel({
    auto: true,
    responsive: true,
    prev: "#prev6",
    next: "#next6",
    scroll: { items:1,duration: 200}, //set duration here
    pagination: "#pager6",
    mousewheel: true,
    items: {
        visible: 1,
        width: 200
    }
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/bTHnL/

Answer (score 4):

The `duration` inside the `scroll` object sets the time (in ms) it takes for the scrolling animation. To set the timeout between elements you need to set `auto` to a number

So an example for this:

```
$('#carousel').carouFredSel({
    auto: 3000, //Set the time between transitions
    scroll : {
        duration: 1000 //The duration of the scroll animation
    }   
});
```